# Error: spawn python ENOENT

Tags: python, node.js, compilation

I am using ['compile-run' package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compile-run) of node to compile and run a piece of python code.When the api endpoint is hit I get the following error:

```
events.js:182
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn python ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:1019:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:192:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:374:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

My code for the endpoint is:

```
router.post('/run',function(req,res){


   var code=req.body.code;
    var input="";
    compile_run.runPython(code, input, function (stdout, stderr, err) {
        if(!err){
        console.log("stout "+stdout);
         console.log("stderr "+stderr);
         }
         else{
         console.log(err);
         }
     });
 });
```

The code sent from the front end is : print "hello"

I am unable to find out the exact problem. Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have python installed on your system?

Comment: yes I have python installed on my system  @nadavvadan

Comment: Then perhaps it is not in your `PATH`?

Comment: Are you using linux/unix-based or windows?

Comment: thank you @nadavvadan. The path was not correctly set.

Comment: Great. my next suggestion would've been to look for another package, as this one calls for `python` directly, while a windows system might have required `python.exe`.

anyway, glad everything worked out